# Get JSONArray from Retrofit Response

Tags: android, arrays, json, api, retrofit

//Here is the `JSON` I am getting from the server

```
{
"code": "200",
"contentType": "Json",
"data": [{
    "createdon": "2017-12-2",
    "fname": "abhay",
    "mobileno": "1234567890",
    "userid": 1234,
    "profileimagepath": null
}],
"maxjsonlength": 1233,
"message": "Success",
"status": true
}
```

Could not parse `JSONArray` while getting values for code, contentType, `maxjsonlength`, message, status from Retrofit response. Please help me rectify the issue.

```
//Model 
public class Example {

@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private String code;
@SerializedName("contentType")
@Expose
private String contentType;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;
@SerializedName("maxjsonlength")
@Expose
private Integer maxjsonlength;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Boolean status;

public String getCode() {
return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
this.code = code;
}

public String getContentType() {
return contentType;
}

public void setContentType(String contentType) {
this.contentType = contentType;
}

public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

public Integer getMaxjsonlength() {
return maxjsonlength;
}

public void setMaxjsonlength(Integer maxjsonlength) {
this.maxjsonlength = maxjsonlength;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public Boolean getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
this.status = status;
}

}

// Model of data JsonArray
public class Datum {

@SerializedName("createdon")
@Expose
private String createdon;
@SerializedName("fname")
@Expose
private String fname;
@SerializedName("mobileno")
@Expose
private String mobileno;
@SerializedName("userid")
@Expose
private Integer userid;
@SerializedName("profileimagepath")
@Expose
private Object profileimagepath;

public String getCreatedon() {
return createdon;
}

public void setCreatedon(String createdon) {
this.createdon = createdon;
}

public String getFname() {
return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
this.fname = fname;
}

public String getMobileno() {
return mobileno;
}

public void setMobileno(String mobileno) {
this.mobileno = mobileno;
}

public Integer getUserid() {
return userid;
}

public void setUserid(Integer userid) {
this.userid = userid;
}

public Object getProfileimagepath() {
return profileimagepath;
}

public void setProfileimagepath(Object profileimagepath) {
this.profileimagepath = profileimagepath;
}

}
```

//This is how I am sending request to the server:

```
 @Headers({
    "Content-Type:application/json",
    "Bearer:mlm_token"
    })

@GET("api/v1.0/****/TestApi/{id}")
Call<Example> getTestJson(@Query("id") int userId);
```

//This is Retrofit Api code

```
 DrawerMethods msgInterface = (DrawerMethods) NetworkModule
            .getInstance().createClassInstance(DrawerMethods.class);

       Call<Example> mLoginCall = msgInterface.getTestJson(userId);
        mLoginCall.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    //SomeCode
                    }else
                        Toast.makeText(TodayMessage.this, "Invalid credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(TodayMessage.this, "Failed to get Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(TodayMessage.this, "Failed to get Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(TodayMessage.this, "Unable to connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use this website: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @NabinBhandari I use the same.

Comment: @Ankita can you try with removing null `private List<Datum> data = null;` **remove = null**

Comment: @ND Yes, I have tried that too

Comment: @Ankita does it throw any exception? or u r getting null for all values?

Comment: Please put retrofit API code in your post.

Comment: @Raghavendra In the Response it shows null for "data"(JSONArray) while I am getting value for other keys available .

Comment: Try commenting `profileimagepath` fetching code and then try it, if it works then that means you are not getting a object for it.

Comment: @Ankita just to test can u change profileimagepath type to String and try once?

Comment: @Anmol and Raghavendra I have tried Commenting "profileimagepath" and making it string but it does not help

Comment: @Ankita Did u try with String type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Headers({
"Content-Type:application/json",
"Bearer:mlm_token"
})

@GET("api/v1.0/****/TestApi/{id}")
//Call<Get> savePost(@Query("id") int userId)
Call<Get> savePost(@Path("id") int userId);
```

Replacing @Query to @Path solved my problem, did not change anything else in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Always try to use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to create JSON POJO.
For your project please add the following 2 model class

//Get Model

```
 public class Get {

    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private String code;
    @SerializedName("contentType")
    @Expose
    private String contentType;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Datum> data = null;
    @SerializedName("maxjsonlength")
    @Expose
    private Integer maxjsonlength;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Boolean status;

    public String getCode() {
    return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
    return contentType;
    }

    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
    this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
    }

    public Integer getMaxjsonlength() {
    return maxjsonlength;
    }

    public void setMaxjsonlength(Integer maxjsonlength) {
    this.maxjsonlength = maxjsonlength;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
    return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
    }

    public Boolean getStatus() {
    return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
    }

 }
```

//FOR MODEL Datum

```
public class Datum {

@SerializedName("createdon")
@Expose
private String createdon;
@SerializedName("fname")
@Expose
private String fname;
@SerializedName("mobileno")
@Expose
private String mobileno;
@SerializedName("userid")
@Expose
private Integer userid;
@SerializedName("profileimagepath")
@Expose
private Object profileimagepath;

public String getCreatedon() {
return createdon;
}

public void setCreatedon(String createdon) {
this.createdon = createdon;
}

public String getFname() {
return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
this.fname = fname;
}

public String getMobileno() {
return mobileno;
}

public void setMobileno(String mobileno) {
this.mobileno = mobileno;
}

public Integer getUserid() {
return userid;
}

public void setUserid(Integer userid) {
this.userid = userid;
}

public Object getProfileimagepath() {
return profileimagepath;
}

public void setProfileimagepath(Object profileimagepath) {
this.profileimagepath = profileimagepath;
}

}
```

For API call use this,

```
//LoginPojo login check
 @Headers({
    "Content-Type:application/json",
    "Bearer:mlm_token"
    })

@GET("api/v1.0/****/TestApi/{id}")
Call<Get> savePost(@Query("id") int userId);
```

And finally, call the web function as follow,

```
    public void logindataPost() {
    mAPIService.savePost().enqueue(new Callback<Get>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Get> call, Response<Get> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("code", "" + response.body().getCode());
                Log.d("contentType", "" + response.body().getContentType());
                Log.d("createdon", "" + response.body().getData().get(0).getCreatedon());
                Log.d("fname", "" + response.body().getData().get(0).getFname());
                Log.d("mobileno", "" + response.body().getData().get(0).getMobileno());
                Log.d("userid", "" + response.body().getData().get(0).getUserid());
                Log.d("profileimagepath", "" + response.body().getData().get(0).getProfileimagepath());
                Log.d("maxjsonlength", "" + response.body().getMaxjsonlength());
                Log.d("message", "" + response.body().getMessage());
                Log.d("status", "" + response.body().getStatus());
            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Get> call, Throwable tr) {
            if (tr != null) {
                Log.d("TEST  Inside fail if", Log.getStackTraceString(tr));
            }
        }
    });

}
```